# Query land use (Raster calculator)

Tags: qgis, raster, query, syntax

I have a land use raster file and am trying to use the raster calculator to query the file for surface water.

The saga formula (11 = surface water band):

(a, 11)

This does not work.

Can anyone help me with the raster calc syntax to perform this?

Comment: I am using QGIS

Answer (score 2):

Try **eq(a, 11)**

With an example of 6x6 dummy raster (values 1-6 and NoData=0): giving `eq(a, 3)`

[image]

It will return a new raster which `3` has become `1`, and others are `0` (thus transparent NoData).

In case you want to extract the cell value **11** itself, try **a*eq(a, 11)** instead (the righthand side image).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the explanation!

Comment: @AndrewRickard kindly accept the answer if your problem is solved.